# What are $\delta$-shock solutions?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, hyperbolic-equations

I studied that a measure valued solution of a conservation law $u_t+f(u)_x=0$ is a measurable map  $\eta : y \rightarrow \eta_y \in Prob(\mathbb{R^n})$ which satisfies $\partial_t(\eta_y, \lambda) +\partial_x (\eta_y, f(\lambda)) =0$ in the sense of distribution on $\mathbb{R^2_+}$. 
In particular, when the conservation law admits  $L^{\infty}$ solution then $\eta_y=\delta_{u(y)}$.

Now I am trying to read "Delta-shock Wave Type Solution of
Hyperbolic Systems of Conservation Laws" by Danilov and Shelkovich [[1]](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0033-569X-05-00961-8). In this article

1. what do they mean by $\delta$-shocks?
2. in which sense these $\delta$-shocks are different from the shocks of the conservation laws?

According to the definition which I stated in the begining any shock solution $u \in L^{\infty}$ can be written as a dirac measure $\eta_y=\delta_{u(y)}$. So:

3. are all shocks $\delta$-shocks?

Please suggest me the reference

---

[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0033-569X-05-00961-8) V.G. Danilov, V.M. Shelkovich (2005): "Delta-shock wave type solution of hyperbolic systems of conservation laws", *Quart. Appl. Math.* **63**, 401-427. [doi:10.1090/S0033-569X-05-00961-8](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0033-569X-05-00961-8)

Comment: Could you please interpret $\delta-$ shock as  a measure valued solution.. i.e. can we write it like $\eta_y$ in the definition of measure valued solution which i mentioned.                  
 Thanks in advance